# So adjective a\an noun for plural subject

Tags: adverbial-phrases

```
so … a …
```

There is another rather formal structure with so + adjective + a/an + noun (see 14).
I had never before met so gentle a person. (= … such a gentle person.)

> This is from Michael Swan's "Practical English Usage".
>   I wonder whether we can write it for plural noun.

For example.

1."They are so beautiful a teacher''.

2."They are so much beautiful teachers"

3."She is so much a beautiful teacher."

Comment: All the three are incorrect.

Comment: Your plural for your original example would be: "I had never met so gentle a people." Perhaps that example will help point you in the right direction?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Let's not confuse plural and uncountable nouns. **Such..a** and **so..a** and even **too..a** can't stand side by side with plural nouns, only singular nouns and in some cases with uncountable nouns.

Comment: To the OP, what SovereignSun has said above is exactly my point. If you can figure out why "people" is OK, but "teachers" is not, you'll see which nouns can fit into your "so + adjective + a/an + noun" construction.

Comment: You may start here, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196784/when-to-use-this-construction-so-adjective-a-noun

Comment: Notice that you can use this construction with verbs most of the time like in **She went so long a distance** or **She sang so beautiful a song**. And in negative statements **She wasn't so good a teacher after all**, however, I guess most people would say **She wasn't such a good teacher after all**. Sometimes we use *that..a* instead of *so..a* to empasize it even more **I wasn't that straight a lover with her** or **He did that bad a thing to her**

Answer (score 3):

You have probably realised by now that English is not consistent, full of little rules that are often poorly articulated - with a lot of exceptions, words or phrases that don't behave like others, not to mention all the confusion of there being words that can be proper verbs or auxiliary verbs. So it shouldn't come entirely as a surprise that this is a phrase that doesn't work with all verbs.

"So X a Y", with X an adjective and Y a noun - generally a **common noun**, a noun that refers to a *type* of thing in general (like *dog*, *map*, *diploma*, *idea* etc.). It forms a noun phrase referring to some specific instance and means that, of the category Y, the specific instance being referred to is unusually Y.

> She sang **so sweet a song**

The song that she sang was unusually sweet.

> He rode **so fast a horse**

The horse that he rode was unusually fast.

Actually, most of the times I've seen it used, it's code an extra bit after the help you understand just how X that particular Y is/was:

> He rode so fast a horse that none could hope to catch him.
>   She sang so sweet a song that the nightingales wept to hear it.

It can also be used to indicate degree relatively:

> I have never met so beautiful a woman.

However, it seems to be increasingly used without that *that*-clause, or any other sort of comparison or degree indicator,  simply to mean that the Y in question was very X. Which is a shame, to my mind, because the full thing is much more poetic, but *c'est la vie*, language changes, and it was ever thus.

Now, it doesn't work with plurals. I know people have mentioned "I had never met so gentle a people", but look at the indefinite article - ***people*** here is singular, not plural. It's a bit of a quirk for that word - *people* can be the plural of *person*, or it can be a singular noun referring to a large, at least vaguely defined group of people, typically connected by some sort of kinship, such as an ethnic group or a nation, or sometimes the members of a particular religious group (possibly thanks to the quotation "a peculiar people"). The potential confusion is such that in some dialects, *persons* is increasingly used when you want to be clear that you are referring to several people as a collection of individuals, rather than a singular mass of people who are connected in some way.

You can't use it with plurals; there is no alternative to the ***a***/***an*** that is part of the formula. So you can't do it for several teachers.

You also don't generally use it with *is*, or possibly (I'm not 100% on this) any form of *to be*. There may be other verbs you can't use it with, but I can't think of any right now. However, negating the verb usually makes it okay, as one of the commenters explained.

The alternative that doesn't suffer from these limitations is ***such***.

> She is **such** a beautiful teacher.
>   They are **such** beautiful teachers.

Your option 3 just makes no sense. Sorry.

You can even use *such* in the degree-indicating or comparison cases:

> She sang such a sweet song that the nightingales wept to hear it.
>   I have never met such a beautiful woman.

However, there is a certain undeniable poetry to "so X a Y".