# Grammar for “pay way too high a price”

Tags: grammar

I understand the meaning intuitively, paying a price too high, or pay a high price, but it puts “a” after the adjective. How does the grammar work here? What is this grammar called?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127801/so-adjective-a-an-noun-for-plural-subject

Comment: @Cardinal thanks, the answer doesn’t say the name of this grammar, has this grammar not been defined linguistically or academically?